# magento 2 - getCreatedAt() returns UTC time and not local time

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, timezone, time

I am trying to get the order time, I fixed the problem with [orders with wrong time stamp in admin panel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189587/magento2-order-timestamp-not-correct). Now I am trying to get the order date in my module.

The problem is

```
$created = $order->getCreatedAt()
```

returns the UTC time and not local time. I tried to use

```
$created = $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate();
```

But this one returns nothing. How should I get the orders date?

Comment: In db, the order time is record in UTC or in local time?

Comment: @Nolwennig yes it is correct also in db, but for some reason it is always 2 hours behind with $order->getCreatedAt()

Comment: it's server time ?

Comment: no the server time is correct, also admin panel time is correct. Somehow in between something happens that api returns wrong time to me

Comment: In https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/201375/24845 xml file. What last upper A value mean in `dateFormat` item?

Comment: That's the timing method from magento 2 core file in 
app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an instance of Timezone to convert it into store's timezone. Here is a very generic example.

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\MyDir;

class MyClass
{
    private $timezone;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone
    ) {
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
    }

    public function myMethod($order)
    {
        $created = $order->getCreatedAt();

        //Convert to store timezone
        $created = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($created));

        //To print or display this you can use following.
        //Feel free to tweak the format
        $dateAsString = $created->format('M j, Y g:i:s A');

        //Proceed further..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved with:

```
$timefc = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface');
$timefc->formatDateTime($product->getCreatedAt())
```

Comment: It showing error for me.

Comment: Object manager is not the way.