# Get data from Quote_items table in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, quoteitem

I am new to Magento 2 so I do not understand much about select data from the table in Localhost also which file I need to create

I want to display data from **Quote_item** table

[image]

in the .phtml file, and What I need to do in **Block** and **xml** file

If anyone can help me step by step, it's very useful for me

Comment: where you want to display quote_item data?? and you need item of specific quote or all the item of quote_item table?

Comment: I already updated my question. Could you please check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data of **quote_item** table using **Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection** collection class like this..

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quoteItemCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection');

foreach ($quoteItemCollection as $quoteItem) 
{
    echo $quoteItem->getName();
    echo $quoteItem->getProductId();
    ......
}
```

I am not recommend you to use object manager instead inject this collecton class in block class of this phtml file and use it here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I when I display the time is wrong

Comment: Look in localhost time like this 08:58:35 but when I display in my .phtml file like this  01:58:35, 08 and 01??  I do not know why

Comment: yes because you will got localhost time converted into GMT Time.

Comment: this might be help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/221314/66058

Answer (score 1):

You can get quote item collection by quote id using this below way :

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
  .....
  \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
  ......
){
   $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) 
    {
        echo $item->getId()."<br>";
        echo $item->getName()."<br>";
        echo $item->getProductId()."<br>";
    }
}
```

Now, print $items. You'll get data.
Hope, it will helpful for you.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your comment, but I think I need to create Block, xml file and then I want to display in .phtml file, maybe that is more clear for me. Can you help me that thing?

Comment: Object Manager direct use is not good practise. You need to add this answer in your block file and then, need to call function in phtml file. Should I give you all steps?

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need your help so I think yes

Comment: For that, you can take reference from here. Still, if you have any confusion. Then, you can ask here. http://www.rohanhapani.com/create-a-simple-module-in-magento-2/