# Get Quote_item table data

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

How can I fetch the data in the quote_item table for a specific item ? I'm trying to get the product name with "gift" at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data of one quote_item table using this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$itemResourceModel = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item');
$quoteItemFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory ');


$itemId = your id here
$quoteItem = $quoteItemFactory->create();
$itemResourceModel->load($quoteItem, $itemId);

echo $quoteItem->getName();
echo $quoteItem->getProductId();
```

I am not recommending you to use the object manager instead inject two classes in a block class of this phtml file and use it here.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can get data of quote_item table using

> Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection collection
>   class

like this..

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quoteItemCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection');

foreach ($quoteItemCollection as $quoteItem) 
{
    echo $quoteItem->getName();
    echo $quoteItem->getProductId();
    ......
}
```

I am not recommending you to use the object manager instead inject this collection class in a block class of this phtml file and use it here.

And please check refer :

[Get data from Quote_items table in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280540/get-data-from-quote-items-table-in-magento-2)

Comment: What if I want to get only one item with a given id ?

Comment: what want you get ??

Comment: I want to get one item in the collection, not all of them. For example, I want to get the data associated  with item_id equal to 164