# Magento 2 - Orders saving as local timzezone

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3, timezone

I have an issue with how a Magento 2 store is saving orders.

My understanding was that orders are saved in UTC.

However, when new orders are placed, it is saving them as our local timezone in the database (AEST)

We have a mixture of orders that have been migrated from Magento 1 (UTC) and new orders placed in M2 (for some reason currently being saved as AEST), so when it displays these dates, its not performing any conversion on them at all and it looks like they were placed 10 hours earlier. Newly placed orders "look" correct in the backend. Older migrated orders are 10 hours off.

I have updated the settings under

> Stores -> Configuration -> General ->Locale Options -> Timezone to
>   reflect "Australian Eastern Standard Time".

Should this impact how the orders are actually saved in the database? I would assume it would work the same way as Magento 1 - however looking at the timestamps it definitely is saving them as AEST in the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: example of M2 order(top) and migrated M1 order(bottom)]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magento 2 - getCreatedAt() returns UTC time and not local time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201392/magento-2-getcreatedat-returns-utc-time-and-not-local-time)

Answer (score 0):

Order save time in database is depends on set timezone on mysql server. Magento setting is only use for display purpose.

I recommend that set server timezone UTC and set mangeto timezon as your local timezone.

I hope this information will help you.

Please let me know still if you have any question.