# how to get the local time for the orders?

Tags: magento2

i have a problem with time zone , when i make an order , the time for this  command ('created_at') is not the local time , it returns the UTC time and not local time

so for that i find the solution here [magento 2 - getCreatedAt() returns UTC time and not local time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201392/magento-2-getcreatedat-returns-utc-time-and-not-local-time)

but in my case i am working with the function addColumn() to display the date

can anyone help me to implement that in my case

```
$this->addColumn('m_created_at', array(
            'header'       => __('Date :'),
            'index'        => 'm_created_at',
            'type'         => 'm_datetime',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',
        ));
```

my local variables :

```
'locale' => [
                    'firstday' => '0',
                    'weekend' => '0,6',
                    'datetime_format_long' => '%A, %B %e %Y [%I:%M %p]',
                    'datetime_format_medium' => '%a, %b %e %Y [%I:%M %p]',
                    'datetime_format_short' => '%m/%d/%y [%I:%M %p]',
                    'date_format_long' => '%A, %B %e %Y',
                    'date_format_medium' => '%a, %b %e %Y',
                    'date_format_short' => '%m/%d/%y',
                    'language' => 'en',
                    'code' => 'fr_FR',
                    'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
                    'weight_unit' => 'kgs',
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
this->addColumn(
        'm_created_at',
        [
            'header' => __('Date'),
            'index' => 'm_created_at',
            'type'      => 'date',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',
        ]
    );
```

Time Zone Problem:

```
Go to Configuration > General > locale Options > Time Zone
```

**Set the Server time zone and Magento Time zone the same for this Problem.**

Comment: thank you brother for the response , i tried the above code it didn't work

Comment: try to check the above configuration of time zone

Comment: Can you check please the code above, i have updated my question @Devidas